# Counting neighbours in conway's game of life using python

Tags: python

Hello guys I am trying to do conway's game of life as a beginner, however I keep getting IndexError: list index out of range, I am not sure why it happens, can you guys help? thank you!

```
def count_neighbors(x, y, G):
    count= 0
    n=len(G)
    if x>0:
        if y>0:
            if G[x-1][y-1]=='x':
                count +=1
        if y<n-1:
            if G[x-1][y+1]=='x':
                count +=1
            if G[x-1][y]=='x':
                count +=1
    if y>0:
        if G[x][y-1]=='x':
            count +=1
        if y<n-1:
            if G[x][y+1] =='x':
                count +=1
    if x<n-1:
        if y>0:
            if G[x+1][y-1] =='x':
                count +=1
    if y<n-1:
        if G[x+1][y+1] =='x':
            count +=1
        if G[x+1][y]=='x':
            count +=1
    return count
```

Comment: Which line is getting the error? What's the value of all the variables when this happens?

Comment: When you create the grid, do you ensure that all rows have `n` elements?

Comment: If `x` or `y` is 0, you're accessing the index `-1` of an array, which will throw an index error.

Comment: if y<n-1:
        if G[x+1][y+1] =='x':
            count +=1
        if G[x+1][y]=='x':
            count +=1
The last part seems to be the problem

Comment: There are two options when dealing when the edge cases in Conway's life game. The first option is to add additional empty dummy  cells all around the "board" so a 10x10 board requires 12x12 cells. Nothing must me allowed to be "born" in these extra cell. It this case, counting neighbors should be done only for the real - not the dummy - cells and then no special checking is required for out-of-limits x and y.

Comment: A second option is to allow the board to "wrap around" so that that the points at an exge have neighbors at the opposite edge.

Comment: more elegant solution could be something where you create cartesian product of all coordinates to consider. Can remove huge amount of if statements.

Answer (score 0):

You're not checking if x < n-1 here, and therefore G[x+1] could be out of bounds:

```
    if y<n-1:
        if G[x+1][y+1] =='x':
            count +=1
        if G[x+1][y]=='x':
            count +=1
```

Upon further inspection, it seems that you should just indent this block once, so that it falls under the `if x<n-1:` check you wrote above.

Your code is also assuming that G is a square matrix (height == width); if this is not the case, then you will also run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic answer is to use loops:

```
def count(x,y,G):
    counts = 0
    for dy in (-1,0,1):
        for dx in (-1,0,1):
            if not (dx and dy) and x+dx in range(n) and y+dy in range(n) and G[y+dy][x+dx] == 'x':
                counts += 1
    return counts
```

Another trick I've used is to have a list of the possible moves:

```
dirs = (
    (-1,-1), ( 0,-1), ( 1,-1),
    (-1, 0),          ( 1, 0),
    (-1, 1), ( 0, 1), ( 1, 1)
)

def count(x,y,G):
    counts = 0
    for dx,dy in dirs:
        if x+dx in range(n) and y+dy in range(n) and G[y+dy][x+dx] == 'x':
            counts += 1
    return counts
```

Answer (score 0):

Update: I just realized I have the wrong rule for 4 neighbors! Fixing...

Update #2: Fixed 2 rules.

I have written numerous programs to play Conway's life game in many languages (including assebly language). None of the programs were easy nor short!

Here is a pure numpy solution to Conway's life game that not only computes all neighbor counts in a few lines of code but also goes on to calculate the next generation in a total of only 9 numpy statements.

```
import numpy as np

# A 5x5 numpy array represents a 3x3 "world" where the outer edge cells
# will always remain equal to 0.
G = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
print('G ---------- Original generation')
print(G)

# Create array S (sum) where each element is the sum of the 3x3 cell surrounding
# the same element in the G array.
S = np.zeros_like(G)
S[1:-1, 1:-1] = sum(G[i:G.shape[0]-2+i, j:G.shape[1]-2+j]
        for i in range(0, 3) for j in range(0, 3))
print('S ---------- Provisional neighbor counts')
print(S)

# Since the sums in S include the center cell we subtract the extra values by
# subtracting G from S!
X = np.subtract(S, G)
print('X ---------- Adjusted neighbor counts')
print(X)

# Apply Conway's rules of life
X[((X == 1) | (X > 3)) & (G == 1)] = -1  # Death
X[((X == 1) | (X > 3)) & (G == 0)] = 0 # No change if G is already equal to 0
X[X == 2] = 0  # Survival
X[(X == 3) & (G == 1)] = 0  # No change if G is already equal to 1
X[(X == 3) & (G == 0)] = +1 # Birth otherwise!
print('X ---------- Changes for the next generation')
print(X)

# Apply the calculated changes from X to G
G = np.add(G, X)
print('G ---------- Tada!!! The next generation')
print(G)
```

Output:

```
G ---------- Original generation
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
S ---------- Provisional neighbor counts
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 3 4 3 0]
 [0 4 6 4 0]
 [0 2 3 2 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
X ---------- Adjusted neighbor counts
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 2 3 2 0]
 [0 4 5 4 0]
 [0 1 3 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
X ---------- Changes for the next generation
[[ 0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0 -1  0  0]
 [ 0 -1  1 -1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0]]
G ---------- Tada!!! The next generation
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```